# Do I need to "make dormitory" on every bed in an area?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When making a communal dormitory, does it suffice to make a bedroom off a single bed that overlaps all the other beds, or do I need to do it for every single bed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.** A single bed to anchor the room and mark it a Dormitory will assign all beds to that dormitory.

If you assigned a dormitory to each individual bed you'd get a dozen individual overlapping dorms. Probably not what you want as they'd divide the quality value.

Answer (score 0):

Something to note however: if the room is sufficiently large (and therefore high-valued) the penalty of multiple rooms is negligible and will result in every dwarf having a "personal palace"

Comment: IIRC, the penalty for multiple rooms is that the value is divided by the number of overlapping rooms.  If you make a huge number of closely-packed beds into overlapping rooms, the rooms will each have a net value of one bed.  Throwing in a few ludicrously-valuable decorations could certainly overwhelm this effect, though.

Comment: Actually it isn't necessary to have high value items, since the size of the room itself is a factor in its value, a big enough room (e.g 20x20) filled with beds along the side (40 beds) should result in 40 "Royal Bedrooms" even despite the overlap.